# Record audio using getUserMedia when the HTML page runs inside WKWebView or UIWebView in an iOS app?

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, wkwebview, getusermedia

Is it possible to record audio using getUserMedia when the HTML page runs inside WKWebView or UIWebView in an iOS app?

I tried the test page [Recording audio in Chrome for Android using web audio API and navigator.getUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054273/recording-audio-in-chrome-for-android-using-web-audio-api-and-navigator-getuserm?lq=1), loading it to a `WKWebView` by

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    WKWebView *w = [WKWebView new];
    self.view = w;
    [w loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://jsfiddle.net/JCFtK/embedded/result/"]]];
}
```

but the record button does not seem to do anything.

Then I tried [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) and loading the sample page. It says `navigator.getUserMedia not present!` and I can't continue.

So is there anything I can do to configure `WKWebView` so that it accepts `getUserMedia` or is it not supported at all?

P.S. I am a newbie in iOS things.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.getUserMedia` is not supported in Safari browsers (desktop and mobile)
Take a look at this:
https://github.com/common-tater/wkwebview-getusermedia-shim

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia it should work in Safari now, but not using WKWebView/UIWebView (e.g. build from Cordova), nor in PWA context (see note n°3).
Demand for better support seems rather strong : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88052